# List<T> on Cache (Security Operations)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, locking, thread-safety

I'm developing an web app using asp.net mvc.

I have a List in Cache (List of product class of my model). So, I do CRUD operations on this cached list. I know that HttpContext.Current.Cache is typeSafe but the list no. I'd like to know, what is the best way to do my operations to be thread safe to avoid conflicts ?

My code are something like this:

```
public static class ProjectCached {
    const string key = "ProductList";
    // my cached list
    public static IList<Product> Products {
       get {
           if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] == null) {
              HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, /* get data from database */, ...);
           }
           return (List<Product>)HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
       }
    }
    // my methods (operations on cached list)
    public static void Increase(long id) {
        var item = Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (item != null) {
          item.Prince += 1;
          item.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        }       
    }

    public static void Remove(long id) {
        var item = Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (item != null) {
            Products.Remove(item);
        }       
    }
    // others methods
```

}

I will have a lot of users writing on this cached list at the same time...

I know that I can to use "lock" keyword but where need I to put this ? On my object finded? on my list?

thanks

Comment: Why do you actually cache those objects in memory? How do you prevent any loss of data when the AppDomain gets unloaded (or your computer crashes?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using IDictionary instead of list, for example `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`

About safe-threading: You can look to using

1. `lock` keyword
2. [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) - to lock only when needed
3. [ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) - if thread-safe implemented in it is enough for you.

UPD: `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is much more advanced than simple `lock` keyword. Using `ReaderWriterLockSlim` allows many readers to get data simultaneously without locks. But when some thread tries to write data, all other threads will be locked for and reading and writing.

Comment: Is there any differenct between lock keyword and ReaderWriterLockSlim ? Thanks man!

Comment: Thanks for awser man, I'll study the possibility. Currently my project is on .Net 3.5, and I'll try to migrate to 4.0. Thanks again!

Comment: @Felipe Always welcome. BTW: Framework 4.0 is tasty, really. Migrate, you won't regret.

Answer (score 0):

You have to lock it before searching for the item.

```
private Object syncObject = new Object();

public static void Increase(long id) {        
    lock(syncObject) {
        ...    
    }
}

public static void Remove(long id) {        
    lock(syncObject) {
        ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: If I choose to use lock keyword, need I use it when the thread need to read from cache or only write ? Thanks